# How to pass Rest post call inputs

Tags: java, rest, post, endpoint

I don't understand the logic of how a REST api method is called with webclient when it has inputs needed. Let's say our post method is

```
@Post
@Path(/my_url)
@Produces(Some_Media_Type)
@Consumes(Some_Media_Type)
public returnClass function(inputClass1 arg1, inputClass2 arg2) {
        return new returnClass(arg1,arg2);
    }
```

How do I pass in an instance of inputClass1 and inputClass2?

```
WebTarget tgt = ClientBuilder.newClient()
.target("http://localhost/whatever" +/my_url)
```

Then I need to call a response

```
Response resp = tgt.request(Some_Media_Type).post(Entity.entity(...))
```

Let's just say my Media Type is JSON. So how do I pass in an instance of inputClass1 and inputClass2, is it into entity?

Comment: You can't have two entity bodies like that. An HTTP request should only have one entity body. This is set in stone. Cant change it. Unless you are using `@FormParam` or Muitipart and `@FormDataParam`, your entity parameter will always be limited to one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two entity bodies like that.
What you could do is to create a class that wraps around the 2 classes you need:

```
Class ArgWrapper {
  private Arg1 arg1;
  private Arg2 arg2;
}
```

And then use ArgWrapper as the parameter.